Sound rendering problem in ubuntu 24.04
I upgraded my Linux system from version 23 to 24.04. After the update, I encountered a problem with sound rendering. Upon researching, I found a blog where many people suggested using the command pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start to restart PulseAudio. I installed PulseAudio and used the command pulseaudio --start, which resolved the issue temporarily. However, the problem reoccurs intermittently. Each time, I have to run pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start again, which works but does not provide a permanent solution.
How can I solve this issue completely?
